# React-native iOS app crashes when taking picture

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, react-native, react-native-camera

I am using `react-native-camera` module in my app. Followed instructions to setup Camera using documentation listed [here](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera). After the setup, I can see camera in iOS simulator and also on my iPhone. But when I click on `CAPTURE` button, my app crashes in simulator and I get following error on my iPhone:
[image: iPhone error]

Here is the code :

```
import React from 'react';
import {  Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Camera  from 'react-native-camera';

class NCamera extends React.Component {
    takePicture() {
        alert('Pressed');

        this.camera.capture()
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Camera
                ref={(cam) => {
                    this.camera = cam;
                }}
                style={styles.preview}
                aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}>
                <Text style={styles.capture} onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}>[CAPTURE]</Text>
            </Camera>
        );
    }
}
```

Please note, if I remove `capture` method (code below), the app does not crash and works fine both in simulator and iPhone. So there is definitely some problem with the code below which I am not able to figure out what.

```
this.camera.capture()
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

I forgot to add following to `your_project/ios/your_project/Info.plist` which allows your app to write permission to user's photo library.

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message to user when the photo library is accessed for the first time</string>
```